# Generating Data Matrix in Clojure

Tags: clojure, datamatrix

I have a collection that consists of binary sequences.
I want to generate a [Data Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Matrix) based on that collection. Are there any libraries in Clojure that facilitate Data Matrix generation?

Answer (score 2):

Edit: [Like this.](http://quil.info/sketches/show/b405fb0e3e332ee469a329ba0c09bef63677a25d224bab03047e1b2201d13376)

I don't know of any specific library but you could easily implement this in Quil?
Here is an example of the [Game of Life in Quil](http://quil.info/sketches/show/647cebb70c414792d4fb09c4ef115a3d5aae062285164ce06276499c0103ffa8) that's very similar to what you are looking for.

Comment: Seems like it should do it. i will take a look it and accept the answer if it works out. Thx,